# Send some product data at publish time in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, send, product

I am trying to develop a plugin for Woocommerce which it sends new published product's information to a Telegram channel. I need to get the price and image of product when it is published. but my code returns empty.

my code :

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'btb_send_telegram_post', 10, 3);
function btb_send_telegram_post( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
if( 
    $old_status != 'publish' 
    && $new_status == 'publish' 
    && !empty($post->ID) 
    && in_array( $post->post_type,array( 'product'))
    ) {
        // product is new published.
        $product = wc_get_product ( $post->ID );
        $message = $product->get_short_description()."\r\n";
      $message .= "price : ". $product->get_price()."\r\n";
      $message .= " regular price : ". $product->get_regular_price() ."\r\n";
      $message .= "sale price : ". $product->get_sale_price()."\r\n";
      btb_send_message($message);
    }
```

I think it is because the changing status of product to publish occurs before it completely saved in database. because when I save a draft before publish it returns correct prices. for that matter I need to do one of these two approaches:

1. Save product as a draft by my code before publish .
2. Use another action which it triggers after product meta is saved completely.

And now I don't have any idea how to do both of above approaches.
any advice will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, what about using [hooks](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/) on this topics `product.created`, `product.updated` and `product.deleted` i personally never used them yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2** *(the product data is not anymore empty)*

You could try this custom function hooked in **`save_post`** action hook:

```
// Only on WooCommerce Product edit pages (Admin)
add_action( 'save_post', 'send_telegram_post', 50, 3 );
function send_telegram_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if ( $post->post_type != 'product') return; // Only products

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id; // Exit if it's an autosave

    if ( $post->post_status != 'publish' )
        return $post_id; // Exit if not 'publish' post status

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id; // Exit if user is not allowed

    // Check if product message has already been sent (avoiding repetition)
    $message_sent = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_message_sent', true );
    if( ! empty($message_sent) )
        return $post_id; // Exit if message has already been sent


    ## ------------ MESSAGE ------------ ##

    // Get active price or "price" (we check if sale price exits)
    $price = empty( $_POST['_sale_price'] ) ? $_POST['_regular_price'] : $_POST['_sale_price'];
    $message = '';
    $rn = "\r\n";

    // Title
    if( ! empty( $_POST['post_title'] ) )
        $message .= 'Title : ' . $_POST['post_title'] . $rn;

    // Short description
    if( ! empty( $_POST['excerpt'] ) )
        $message .= 'Description : ' . $_POST['excerpt'] . $rn;

    // Active price
    if( ! empty( $price ) )
        $message .= 'Price : ' . $price . "\r\n";

    // Regular price
    if( ! empty( $_POST['_regular_price'] ) )
        $message .= 'Regular price : ' . $_POST['_regular_price'] . $rn;

    // Sale price
    if( ! empty( $_POST['_sale_price'] ) )
        $message .= 'Sale price : ' . $_POST['_sale_price'] . $rn;

    // Send message custom function
    btb_send_message( $message );

    // Just for testing (uncomment below to enable): 
    // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_message_content', $message ); // Message in database

    // add custom meta field to mark this product as "message sent"
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_message_sent', '1' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you . you did it . very big help. Thank you so much. you are the best

Comment: @mohammadboluki Thank you to be patient… It was not really obvious. I was almost sure about the hook. Glad it's working for you.